# Angular2 data binding pass variable dynamically

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular5

Using Angular(5) I am displaying a list of email addresses giving a form input for each of them. Form input is coming from a child component, so my code is:

```
<div *ngFor="let email of user.emailAddresses; let i = index">
  <form-input label="Email Address:"
              name="EmailAddresses[i].EmailAddress"
              [(ngModel)]="user.emailAddresses[i].emailAddress"
              ngDefaultControl></form-input>
</div>
```

My issue is in 'name' property. I would expect index 'i' to be passed as a number although it pass i itself(letter). What is the way to pass the index properly?

I tried something like:

```
name="EmailAddresses["+'i'+"].EmailAddress"
```

but obviously no success.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Why you don't use `email` from your `ngFor` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to my issue. As I mentioned EmailAddresses[i].EmailAddress is a string not a model - I want this exact text. Although, I need to update dynamically the index.

To the point, the solution is:

```
[name]="'EmailAddresses['+i+'].EmailAddress'"
```

Thank you all for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `email` inside iteration:

```
<div *ngFor="let email of user.emailAddresses; let i = index">
  <form-input label="Email Address:"
              [name]="email.EmailAddress"
              [(ngModel)]="user.emailAddresses[i].emailAddress"
              ngDefaultControl></form-input>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want Angular to interpret the value instead of passing it as a string literal, you need to wrap `name` in square brackets, i.e. `[name]=email.EmailAddress`

Comment: @MikkaRin the API returns "EmailAddresses[0].EmailAddress", "EmailAddresses[1].EmailAddress" etc... I need to pass as a name the word "EmailAddresses[i].EmailAddress" but instead of i, the exact number. I forgot to mention that I use C# data annotation attributes. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From reading your comment, I think what you need is:

```
<div *ngFor="let email of user.emailAddresses; let i = index">
  <form-input label="Email Address:"
              [name]="'EmailAddresses[' + i + '].EmailAddress'"
              [(ngModel)]="user.emailAddresses[i].emailAddress"
              ngDefaultControl></form-input>
</div>
```

This will give `EmailAddresses[0].EmailAddress` etc. as the value